# structure data via aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

i have been tring to create statistics for a collections via the aggregate fremwork in mongodb, i want create an object that contains user id, and arry that contains the calls directions the user had (outbound, inbound etc.) the total air duration of each direction and the total amount of calls that made at the spesific direction.

for example :

I have this document :

```
{
    "userId" : "628pp9d91ce06ba3ed6cb0pf6",
    "date" : "1655983001341",
    "direction" : "outbound",
    "duration" : 35.0,
    "network" : null,
    "status" : "completed",
    "from" : "src-1",
    "company" : "companyName",
}
```

and i tried to make a statistics docs via agreggate like that :

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match : { company : "companyName"}},
    {$group : { _id : "$userId", data : { $addToSet : { direction : "$direction", duration : { $sum : "$duration"}, amount :  { $sum : 1} } } } }
])
```

the expected value need to be :

```
{
    "_id" : "---",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "direction" : "unanswered",
            "duration" : 26.0,
            "amount" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "direction" : "outbound",
            "duration" : 863.0,
            "amount" : 3.0
        }
    ]
}
```

but the output i gets is :

```
{
    "_id" : "6268f634106db6972be89241",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "direction" : "unanswered",
            "duration" : 12.0,
            "amount" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "direction" : "outbound",
            "duration" : 767.0,
            "amount" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "direction" : "outbound",
            "duration" : 41.0,
            "amount" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "direction" : "outbound",
            "duration" : 55.0,
            "amount" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "direction" : "unanswered",
            "duration" : 1.0,
            "amount" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "direction" : "unanswered",
            "duration" : 13.0,
            "amount" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

what do i do wrong ?

Comment: Try grouping with two fields: `userId` and `direction`.

Comment: i tried,  now i have a document for each pair of user and direction, this is what you ment? can i add a stage to agraggete that will narrow it to the format i want?

Comment: Now you can do a grouping on `userId` and the `$push` the values into an array - in the next stage.

Comment: how can i add a totalDour field that sum the duration of all items on arry ?

Comment: You can use `$reduce`, or maybe `$sum` (`$sum` can also be used in other than `$group` stage).